# Reading data info from file using regular expressions

Tags: c++, file, objective-c++

I want to create class called FileManager which saves and loads data from file (save.ini)

Below I'll put my data file format:

```
property=value;
property2=value2;
property3=value3;
```

I'm wondering how can I create method that reads just the right side, after = sign. Probably I have to use regular expressions there but still I dont know how can I load them to array or vector. I tried using getline() but something goes wrong ;D

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please show the code you have tried and include the error message. See also [mcve]

Comment: Strange, it works for me just fine.

Comment: You don't need a regex - that's overkill for this task.  After reading in the line, just use `std::string::find` to search for the equals sign and then use `std::string::substr` to extract the trailing part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex, you can easily write your own parser.

The following code parses a single line and saves the value in a provided `unordered_map`:

```
void parseLine(char * line, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> & values)
{
    // Find entry name
    const char * name = line;
    for (char c = *line; c != '='; c = *(++line));
    *line = '\0';

    // Find entry value
    const char * val = line + 1;
    for (char c = *line; c != ';'; c = *(++line));
    *line = '\0';

    // Insert value in map
    values.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(name, val));
}
```

It simply scans the line until `'='` and `';'` are found. Note that this only works if the syntax is correct (no spaces, semi-colon at the end), but I think it's what you want.

Then to parse a file:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> values;
FILE * fp = fopen("somefile", "r");
if (fp)
{
    char line[128]; // replace with max line length
    while (fgets(line, 128, fp))
        parseLine(line, values);
}

fclose(fp);
```

`fgets(line, 128, fp)` reads up to `128` characters of the current line of the file `fp` and saves it in the buffer `line`. When it reaches EOF it returns `nullptr` and the loop ends.

Of course you can wrap this inside a class of your choice.